# SQLAlchemy filter query "column LIKE ANY (array)"

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, any

Hi SQLAlchemy experts out there, here's a tricky one for you:

I'm trying to write a query that resolves into something like:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable where my_column LIKE ANY (array['a%', 'b%'])
```

using SQLAlchemy:

```
foo = ['a%', 'b%']

# this works, but is dirty and silly
DBSession().query(MyTable).filter("my_column LIKE ANY (array[" + ", ".join(["'" + f + "'" for f in token.tree_filters]) + "])")

# something like this should work (according to documentation), but doesn't (throws "AttributeError: Neither 'AnnotatedColumn' object nor 'Comparator' object has an attribute 'any'"
DBSession().query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.my_column.any(foo, operator=operators.like)
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elixir/SQLAlchemy equivalent to SQL "LIKE" statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3325467/elixir-sqlalchemy-equivalent-to-sql-like-statement)

Answer (score 27):

Use [or_()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#common-filter-operators) and `like()`, the following code should satisfy your need well:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_

foo = ['a%', 'b%']
DBSession().query(MyTable).filter(or_(*[MyTable.my_column.like(name) for name in foo]))
```

A where condition `WHERE my_column LIKE 'a%' OR my_column LIKE 'b%'` would be generated from above code.

As for why your `any()` didn't work, I think it's because it requires `my_column`  to be a list (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572679/filtering-by-association-attributes-with-sqlalchemy-association-proxy)), and, for instance, `query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.my_list_column.any(name='abc'))` is to return `MyTable` rows if any element in `my_list_column` column (a list) of that row is named with 'abc', so it's actually quite different from your need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using or_() was another solution that I thought of, but didn't want that because it can make the query quite long. But still better than my dirty solution, I guess.

Comment: @user1599438 I'm afraid you need to use `or_()` for this case, and it's actually not that long :p

Answer (score 17):

You can try to use [any_()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.any_)

In your case it would look something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import any_

foo = ['a%', 'b%']
DBSession().query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.my_column.like(any_(foo)))
```

Comment: How to use `like any` with JSON field like {"a": ["1", "5"]} if I want to find any item from an array [1, 7, 9]?